# Gradle not syncing after importing a project and shows en error

Tags: android, gradle, import, synchronization

Gradle not syncing after importing a project and shows en error

```
Error:No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android'
Error:No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android'
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

Comment: Can you update your question with build.gradle file?

Comment: restart your android studio and try

Comment: Android studio restarted, but no use.

Comment: Try updating your compile SDK version to a newer version

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this problem by opening

[image]

then

[image]

I solve this problem.

Comment: I really solve the problem by this way,I don't know why you can't@nigam-patro